# Get elements "created" between 9am and 7pm, on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a DateTime field called *created*.
¿Is there a way to query elements that were created on any date but on a specific time interval, as the title suggests, using *find* or other method?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql I make a datetime field that is yearmonthdayhrminsec.. 20150313132300 this way its completely numeric and not dependent on different databases way of handling date and time. This way I can query on a numeric range.....a lot easier for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving some lines of code here. Please modify following code according to your requirements.

following function frame_date() will get time according to hour,mins,secs and milisecs.

```
function frame_date(gethours, getMins, getSecs, getMiliSecs) {

    var timestamp = new Date();
    var getYear = timestamp.getFullYear();
    var getMnth = timestamp.getMonth();
    var getDate = timestamp.getDate();
    if (getDate < 10) {
        getDate = "0" + getDate;
    }
    if (getMnth < 9) {
        getMnth = parseInt(getMnth) + 1
        getMnth = "0" + getMnth;
    } else {
        getMnth = getMnth + 1;
    }


    var final_framed_date = getYear + "-" + getMnth + "-" + getDate + " " + gethours + ":" + getMins + ":" + getSecs + "." + getMiliSecs;
    return final_framed_date;

}
```

now we will call frame_date() function in new Date() to get date.

```
var nine_am_date = new Date(frame_date(09, 00, 00, 000));// get time of 9 a.m.

var seven_pm_date = new Date(frame_date(19, 00, 00, 000));// get time of 7 p.m.
```

now we will use greater than or less than in created field. its will only fetch between 9a.m. and 7p.m.

```
db.collection('users').find({created: {$gte: nine_am_date, $lte: seven_pm_date}}).sort({created: -1}).toArray(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        //handle error here
    } else {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

Thanks